# How often should I update my content for auto-renewable subscriptions?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement auto-renewable subscription in my app for in-app purchase. As per apple's policy, they say apps using auto-renewable subscription should update their content periodically, how often am I supposed to update my app's content which can only be accessible for users who are currently subscribed to my service? Any help or suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You should do it for your own sake i.e. for your customers. Like if u are providing monthly subscription you should update content in less than a month so that your users will be eager to continue your product for next month.

Comment: Actually I was asking this question with reference to Apple's policy of implementing auto-renewable in-app purchase in apps. Their guidelines are somewhat vague and I am not sure if I can actually implement auto-renewable in-app purchase and not get the app rejected while submitting on appstore.

This is the kind of app in which I want to implement in-app purchase.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51701236/in-app-purchase-in-app-with-static-content-in-web-views-ios